# How to replace a string with a variable part?

Tags: php

I would like to replace each `\x` to `$matches[x]` where x is a number.

It works only for predefined numbers with `str_replace`:

```
str_replace( array(
    '\\1',
    '\\2',
    '\\3',
    '\\4'
), array(
    '$matches[1]',
    '$matches[2]',
    '$matches[3]',
    '$matches[4]'
), $string );
```

Comment: Take a look at [`preg_repalce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Why can't you create the first argument in a dynamic manner, based on the length of the second argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression in [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Code:

```
<?php

$str = '\\2 string \\123 gogog \\123 sda \\342 \\3525 wqe \\234';
echo preg_replace('~(\\\\)(\d+)~', '$matches[$2]', $str);
```

Output:

```
$matches[2] string $matches[123] gogog $matches[123] sda $matches[342] $matches[3525] wqe $matches[234]
```